# Zapf Chancery Cyrillic through external truetype font

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I would like to make use of the Cyrillic characters in this Zapf Chancery font http://allfont.net/download/zapfchanceryctt/ in plain latex/pdflatex

I have installed the font, creating an afm file first with t2a-mod1.enc and then creating the tfm file. Through this, I have been able to use the font with usual Latin characters but not Cyrillic ones. 
I am already including

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Could anyone point out what am I missing?

On a side note, in that link, under the option "Full list of characters (beta)" a table is created. I know there is a latex command to achieve the same but have struggled to remember it for some time now, would appreciate if anyone can identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit hacky way to make this particular font available to pdfLaTeX:

First, copy the font to the current directory. Let its name be **ZapfChanceryCTT.ttf** for the reference.

Second, create the TTF file using **otftotfm** and **q-t2a-uni** encoding:

```
otftotfm -eq-t2a-uni ZapfChanceryCTT.ttf >ZapfChanceryCTT.map
```

Finally, the following TeX file includes the locally created map and shows a few characters from the font:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pdfmapfile{+ZapfChanceryCTT.map}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{ZapfChanceryCTT}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{ZapfChanceryCTT}{m}{n}{<-> ZapfChanceryCTT--q-t2a-uni}{}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{ZapfChanceryCTT}\selectfont
QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG.

СЪЕШЬ ЕЩЕ ЭТИХ МЯГКИХ ФРАНЦУЗСКИХ БУЛОК, ДА ВЫПЕЙ ЧАЮ.

\end{document}
```

If you need this font regularly, you'd probably want to install the map, the metrics and the font itself somewhere inside your ~/texmf tree. Or, you could switch to LuaLaTeX and deal with the font file only.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this, it is working perfectly. Now I know how to load other ttf fonts too in plain Latex.