# Finding an specific cursive Cyrillic character

Tags: symbols, characters, cyrillic

Is there any font in plain Latex of XeTex containing this particular form of the capital Cyrillic Т shown in the picture? 
[image]

I would appreciate if anyone can come up with a way to typeset it in Tex.

I do have a few fonts containing the symbol, but I do not know how to extract it. Please take a look at my previous question [Zapf Chancery Cyrillic through external truetype font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354479/zapf-chancery-cyrillic-through-external-truetype-font)

One of such fonts is this one http://allfont.net/download/zapfchanceryctt/

Comment: You can use any system font which contains such a glyph.

Comment: I'd normally recommend looking at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html but this doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: There is U+1C85 (CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER THREE-LEGGED TE)  (ᲅ) but that's upright the image looks more like a greek pi with an extra stroke. Do you have that symbol in any electronic form (pdf, html etc, that would reveal the font then would be easier to say how to get that into tex)

Comment: It's the U+0442 (CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER TE) in calligraphic style. So, for LuaLaTeX or XeTeX you could easily use any calligraphic cyrillic font. As for pdfLaTeX, I don't know any such font with ready to use metrics.